# How to add new view at the top of an existing view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, pull-to-refresh, swiperefreshlayout

I am stuck, please help me,
I have this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Programmatically i am adding Linear Layout containing ImageView and TextView into LinearLayout of this xml file. Its okay for me. Now in Java i am doing,

```
refreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

            ( new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                }
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
```

Inside setOnRefreshListener I want to add new LinearLayout containing ImageView and TextView on the top of my previous view. That means all my previous LinearLayout which I added programmatically will be placed after new Layouts keeping unchanged.

I can't move from here. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You should be using a listview.

Comment: what's preventing you from adding the new views using refreshLayout.addView(....